# How to format two column OCR PDF into one column

Tags: pdf, ocr, kindle

I am having trouble reading a PDF on my Kindle because the OCR text is displayed in two columns per page.  (IE The book was scanned two pages at a time, them OCR'd.)  How can I format this into one column (or any style for that matter) so that I can read it on my Kindle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version of k2pdfopt can either keep the OCR with [native PDF output option](http://willus.com/k2pdfopt/help/native.shtml) (-mode 2col) or restore the OCR using [its own OCR](http://willus.com/k2pdfopt/help/ocr.shtml).  Also, running the k2pdfopt output through Calibre, as some have suggested, is not necessary if you use the right settings in k2pdfopt.

Edit:  v2.x of k2pdfopt, released 3-Sep-2013, will preserve previously OCR'd text by default even when not used in native PDF output mode (e.g. when re-flowing text).

Comment: Also note that it is possible to run k2pdfopt directly on your kindle using kindlepdfviewer or its forks. Further information and links are given [here](http://superuser.com/a/636833/191912).

Answer (score 1):

Found [this guide.](http://www.howtogeek.com/69481/how-to-convert-pdf-files-for-easy-ebook-reading/)  Basically using [k2pdfopt](http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/) to convert the two columns into just one.  And then running that through Calibre for a cleaner version.

This is a partial solution as it removes the OCR benefits.  The resulting file is only images and thus very large.