# Remove PDF margins and print 2 pages per side

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader, print-to-pdf, pdfcreator, pdftk

I print out a lot of pdf articles, and I'd like to use less paper by printing 2 pages per side. But due to the large margins---both from the original pdf file and added by the printing process---the text is very small when I print 2 pages per side. Is there an automated way to strip out the margins from pdf files, and convert the document to another pdf file that has 2 pages from the old document per page of the new document, with minimal margins?
Thanks.

EDIT: I may have a solution--- pdfjam contains the script "psfnup". It puts two pages per side in a new pdf file. I can crop the files somewhat automatically with Briss. Maybe a two-step solution is as simple as it gets?

Comment: Almost the same question here: http://superuser.com/questions/205126/are-there-tools-available-for-trimming-pdf-margins. Maybe there is something useful for your problem.

Comment: My method has been to use pdfcrop to remove margins, and then acroread was able to print 2 pages up pretty successfully.

Answer (score 4):

[pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam) does nup-imposition and gives you the complete power of [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf); I'm sure you can trim the pages while imposing them. It needs a working TeX-installation, though.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve that by "faking the page size": I added one inch to the height and width and "voilà!", no margins.

Generally, the "multiple pages per sheet" function comes with Adobe Reader or any other standard PDF viewer in the print configuration window.