# How to export a PowerPoint slide to PDF without margin?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, export, microsoft-powerpoint-2013, margins

I have a Microsoft PowerPoint 2013 file that contains a single slide. How can I export it to a PDF file so that the PDF file has no margin?

I.e. instead of:

[image]

I want (if possible with even less margin):

[image]

I am aware of [Are there tools available for trimming PDF margins?](https://superuser.com/q/205126/116475) (I often BRISS) but ideally I would like to directly export to PDF without any margin.

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.