# Is there a Linux tool that can autocrop the white margins in a PDF file

Tags: pdf, crop

I have PDF file in which I want to trim all the white space around as much as possible. It has to automatically detect and do it.

I use Foxit reader and it has option to crop pages automatically while viewing.

But I am looking for a command line solution in Linux.

I tried [PDFCrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net) but it crops all the pages uniformly. I want it to crop based on the white space around each individual page using this command:

```
pdfcrop input.pdf output.pdf
```

But it works only partially, some pages are cropped but some are not.

Comment: Good question. Have you looked at [any of these answers on a similar question posted on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/124692)?

Comment: Edited my question with what i tried based on the link

Comment: see also [Are there tools available for trimming PDF margins?](https://superuser.com/questions/205126/are-there-tools-available-for-trimming-pdf-margins)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best way to remove margins is using [`pdfCropMargins`](https://pypi.org/project/pdfCropMargins/)

Install:

```
pip install pdfCropMargins --upgrade
```

Now we can use the command `pdf-crop-margins` to crop the pdf the way we want

I want to crop all the pages and then add 6bp margin all around. I can do that by

```
pdf-crop-margins -v -p 0 -a -6 input.pdf

-v : Verbose
-p : how much percentage of margin to be retained. We want the bounding box triming all the white margins on all sides. So say 0%
-a : Note: first -p is applied to create a bounding box. 
     IN this option it applies further on the bounding box after -p is applied. we can remove or add margin. Negative means add margin to the bounding box. So it will add 10bp all around after cliping
```

The output file is affixed with `_cropped`

Also I checked the cropped file and all the contents and links are intact.